# bash. execute one script from another and exit

Tags: bash

could you please help me with the following:

i am trying to execute one script - test2 - from the other script test1 using:

```
bash -c  "/test2 -f$(printf " /etc/test2.conf" "$@")"
```

everything is okay. The problem is that test2 script runs continuous and it can't be interrupted and accordingly test1 script is running too. It is unnecessary, test1 should be stopped. 
All i need from  test1 script is to execute test2 script and exit.
I want to do the task only with bash without cron or any similar utilities.

Thank you.

Comment: So you want `test1` to start `test2` and then exit, leaving `test2` running in the background?

Comment: What is that `printf` supposed to be doing? It doesn't actually use `"$@"` at all at the moment. It just prints " /etc/test2.conf".

Answer (score 0):

test1 is already a bash script so it does not need to call bash.  If test2 is executable (has +x set) then it is a command and can be used directly.

```
/path/to/test2 -f$(printf "/etc/test2.conf" "$@") &
```

The ampersand forks the command and leaves it running.  test1 is then able to exit.

---

The above will be terminated by a hangup signal when you close the console, log out, etc.  `nohup` fixes that.

```
nohup /path/to/test2 -f$(printf "/etc/test2.conf" "$@") &
```